# Prevent child scrollview to scroll parent at beginning and end of the list on android (react native)

Tags: android, react-native, scroll, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

Im working with a vertical scrollview and a flatlist nested inside it.

On iOS, when I reach the beginning or end of the list and I keep scrolling, the list bounce and the parent doesnt scroll up or down.

On Android, it start scrolling the parent and this is not what I want.

I tried to disable scroll on the scrollview with the ondrag events from the flatlist but it keep scrolling.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.